# Issues with Custom Validation. Why the form is still invalid

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have this FormGroup with some custom validations. The submit button is disabled until the form is valid. But for whatever reason, I can't validade this form.

Am I missing something here? I can log each control that gets validated as TRUE but not the over all form.

```
initForm() {
     this.form = this.formBuilder.group( {
          first_name: [ '', Validators.required ],
          last_name: [ '', Validators.required ],
          email: [ email || '', Validators.required ],
          mobileNumber: [ '' ],
          city: [ '', this.validateCity.bind( this ) ],
          location: [ null, Validators.required ],
          role: [ '', Validators.required ],
          password: [ '', Validators.required ],
          confirmPassword: [ '', Validators.required ],
          agreedToTerms: [ false, Validators.requiredTrue ]
    }, {
        validators: this.validateForm.bind( this )
    } );
}

private validateForm( group: FormGroup ): ValidationErrors | null {

    const pass1: string = group.get( 'password' ).value;
    const pass2: string = group.get( 'confirmPassword' ).value;

    const email: string = group.get( 'email' ).value;

    const errors: any = {};

    if ( !email ) {

        errors.emailRequired = true;

    } else if ( !email.match( /[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+/ ) ) {

        errors.invalidEmail = true;
    }

    if ( !pass1 ) {
        errors.passwordRequired = true;
    }

    if ( pass1.length < this.minPasswordLength ) {
        errors.passwordMinLength = true;
    }

    const passwordRulesRegEx = new RegExp(/^(?=(.*\d))(?=.*[@#\-_$%^&+=§!\?])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9A-Za-z@#\-_$%^&+=§!\?]{8,}$/);
    if(!passwordRulesRegEx.test(pass1)){
        errors.passwordMinRules = true;
    }

    const passwordRulesNumberRegEx = new RegExp(/^(?=(.*\d))(?=.*[@#\-_$%^&+=§!\?])[0-9A-Za-z@#\-_$%^&+=§!\?]{1,}$/);
    if (!passwordRulesNumberRegEx.test(pass1)) {
        errors.passwordMinRulesNumbersSymbols = true;
    }

    const passwordRulesUppercaseRegEx = new RegExp(/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])[0-9A-Za-z@#\-_$%^&+=§!\?]{1,}$/);
    if (!passwordRulesUppercaseRegEx.test(pass1)) {
        errors.passwordMinRulesUpperLowercase = true;
    }

    if ( pass1 !== pass2 ) {
        errors.passwordMismatch = true;
    }

    return errors;
}
```

Comment: looks like you have type issue in `agreedToTerms: [ false, Validators.requiredTrue ]`  it should say `Validators.required` instead of `Validators.requiredTrue` try it out

Comment: Also for email `email: [ email || '', Validators.required ]` it should be `email: [ email ? email :'', Validators.required ]` use ternary operator

Comment: If none of them works then create a stackblitz example there we can have better idea to debug the issue.

Comment: Hey @KamranKhatti thanks mate! I tried those but still nothing. It's so bizarre. I'll create a stackblitz file

Comment: I'll guess the problem is that you're always returning an object in your validator function, even if its empty. You should check the keys length and pass null if empty: `return Object.keys(errors).length ? errors : null`

Comment: @KorbinianKuhn thanks I tried that, still no dice :/

Comment: but if you just comment out all the errors and return null - does the form get validated? also what is the reason you do bind(this) in this case?

Comment: Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pczv7g?file=src/app/app.component.ts), your code works for me. Are you sure, you filled in correct data e.g. passwords?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I tried, i'm returning null on the validation function and still no dice. The bind was already there when I started in this project. This is so weird...

Comment: @KorbinianKuhn yeah, everything is correct.

Comment: I found out the issue. One of the validators is in a component. I never heard of setting up a component with the `formControlName` property. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you have to implement the `ControlValueAccessor`-Interface. There are many tutorials e.g. [https://medium.com/@majdasab/implementing-control-value-accessor-in-angular-1b89f2f84ebf](Link)

Comment: why not use two validators on each control? remember that you can do some like `email: [ email || '', [Validators.required,Validators.email] ]`?